# PremiumPress Payment Gateway issue: MD5 is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway

Here in the wordpress plugin Premium Press I have integrated payson payment gateway, but there is one small problem: the `MD5` field is not being able to take in any values and not working. Please help me with this.

This is the code for taking input for `MD5` values in a form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MD5" value=" < ?php echo get_option('gateway_payson_receiver');('SellerEmail'); ('OkUrl'); ('GuaranteeOffered'); ('ExtraCost'); ('Cost'); ?>"/>
```

This is what have to be calculated in another file *`send.php`*:

```
 $MD5string = $SellerEmail . ":" . $Cost . ":" . $ExtraCost . ":" . $OkUrl . ":" . $GuaranteeOffered . $Key;
 $MD5Hash = md5($MD5string);

 ('ExtraCost'); ('Cost'); ?>"/>
```

I am trying to test it in: https://www.payson.se/testagent/default.aspx
But for MD5 its not calculating any values.

Please help me if possible.

Edit: I put the extra spaces after value=" and also inside < ?php because stackoverflow was not recognising the code and not displaying, that is not a problem. Inside the real code there is no space there.

Comment: What exactly is not working how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give many details, but I couldn't help noticing this:

```
...me="MD5" value=" < ?php echo get_option('gateway_payson_receiver');('SellerEmail'); ('OkUrl'); ('GuaranteeOffered'); ('ExtraCost'); ('Cost'); ?>
```

- There is an extra space after the open quote mark `value="`.
- The code inside is not PHP, due to the space between < and ?, but text.
- There are no separators and in the calculation you seem to use the : separator.

According to the Payson page you supplied,

> *MD5 - Obligatorisk - Du saknar alla parametrar för att beräkna MD5, du skall ha med: SellerEmail,Cost,ExtraCost,OkUrl,GuaranteeOffered samt din nyckel*

When you display that form, you should have already available the following variables:

```
$SellerEmail
$Cost
$ExtraCost
$OkUrl
$GuaranteeOffered
$Key
```

and output a hidden form field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="MD5" value="<?php echo md5("$SellerEmail:$Cost:$ExtraCost:$OkUrl:$GuaranteeOffered$Key"); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

nothing work with those guyz from premiumpress!
i add diffdrent payment gateways pluggin i took on their website ( fedapay & cinetpay) none work properly and no one is able to fix the problem...i finally ask for refund

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32795268)